# Add totals to Table from MYSQL PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am using the following code to generate tables from data from my database. it groups the data by the employee. What I need is to display the totals for the last four columns at the end of each employees table. The Hours, OT, Travel and TOT columns.

Code:

```
$current_user_name = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // listing a new employee? Output the heading, start the table
    if ($row['user_name'] != $current_user_name) {
            if ($current_user_name !== false)
                  echo '</table>'; echo '[divider_padding]';// if we're changing employee, close the table
        echo '
            <h5>'.$row['last_name'].', '.$row['first_name'].'</h5>[minimal_table]
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th class="tableleft">Description</th>
                <th class="tableleft">Job</th>
                <th class="tableleft">Activity</th>
                <th class="tableleft">Comments</th>
                <th class="tableright">Hours</th>
                <th class="tableright">OT</th>
                <th class="tableright">Travel</th>
                <th class="tableright">TOT</th>

                </tr>';

            $current_user_name = $row['user_name'];
    }
    // output the row of data
    echo '<tr>
        <td style="width:75px">'.$row['labor_date'].'</td>
        <td class="tableleft">'.$row['description'].'</td>
        <td class="tableleft">'.strtoupper($row['job']).'</td>
        <td class="tableleft">'.$row['activity'].'</td>
        <td class="tableleft">'.$row['comments'].'</td>
        <td class="tableright">'.$row['rthours'].'</td>
        <td class="tableright">'.$row['othours'].'</td>
        <td class="tableright">'.$row['trthours'].'</td>
        <td class="tableright">'.$row['tothours'].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';}

echo '</table>[/minimal_table]'; // close the final table

}
?>
```

I am stuck after trying some tests and can not figure this out.

This is the query gathering the data:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE labor_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' Order by last_name, labor_date ASC");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so... `$rthours += $row['rthours']`, then output that total somewhere else once you're done with any particular employee.

Comment: Yes, that works, I just can not figure out where to put it. Every time I place the code it ends up not at the bottom of each table. I have tried after the closing table row of the output of data section. I have tried before the closing table bracket at the top of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is missing an open bracket:

```
if ($current_user_name !== false)
```

Should be:

```
 if ($current_user_name !== false) {
```

Comment: That Breaks the code. When not there code works. This code is wrapped in an else statement right above, that may be why you see that a bracket is needed. The very bottom bracket wraps the else code.

Comment: Changed it to: `if ($current_user_name !== false){
                  echo '</table>'; echo '[divider_padding]';}`

Comment: So just before echo '</table>'; add a line that echos out another <tr></tr> with your totals data. If your table tags are being closed, that should work. Remember to unset($rthours) or set it equal to 0 when you open the new table for each new employee.

Comment: THANKS! That works BUT the last table does not show the totals.

Comment: Figured it out. Place another row before the close last table tag as well. Thanks again!